# Resume browsing on Chrome Custom Tab

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I am working on an special oauth flow on Android. I have an activity `A` which can delegate the authentication to a webpage using a `CustomTabIntent` launched by UI-less Activity `B`. Once the authentication finishes it redirects with a deep link that `B` intercepts and closes the activities clearing the backstack which looks like

`A` -> `B` -> `CustomTab`

So when it finishes `B` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` it goes back to `A`

Now for a new feature the difference is that the deep link intercepted by `B` needs to open `C` to do some permission management. I am able to do that by just finishing `B` and launching `C`. However once `C` finishes I need to take my user back to the browser to finish the authentication so I need a backstack that looks like

`A` -> `B` -> `CustomTab` ->`C`

But I seem unable to launch `C` on top of `CustomTab` without closing the later. Closing it is not an option since I need my user to continue at the point where he left the browser. Another option would be if I could close the Custom Tab but later resume the browser at the state it was closed. But I haven't been able to find a way to do neither of these.

Now to complicate the problem more, `C` could be a new instance of `A` ending with something like

`A` -> `B` -> `CustomTab` ->`A2`

Therefore launching my activities as single tasks is not an option.

If someone has been able to launch an activity on top of a custom tab without closing it I would really appreciate your help. Or if you have any other idea to tackle this problem it would be welcome.